# Custom ADF Cartridge not being Executed. after being configured in cd_ambient_conf

Tags: configuration, ambient-data-framework

Good Morning.

I am having problems after deploying the skeleton of a custom cartridge. I've done  a couple of cartridges before but this time it is driving me crazy.

After adding the cartridge conf in (cd_ambient_config.xml ) I am executing my claimStoreTest.aspx page to see which claims are available in my context...and guess what!...I can not see any of my 4 claims, I don't even see anything about the execution of my processor in the logs.

here is the configuration of the cartridge :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CartridgeDefinition Version="6.1"
    Uri="taf:cartridge:client" Description="cartridge that gets data from a cookie for the PoC"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xsd">
    <ClaimDefinitions>
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim1"
            Scope="SESSION" Description="claim1" />
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim2"
            Scope="SESSION" Description="claim2" />
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim3"
            Scope="SESSION" Description="claim3" />
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim4"
            Scope="SESSION" Description="claim4" />
    </ClaimDefinitions>
    <ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
        <ClaimProcessorDefinition Uri="taf:claimprocessor:client"
            ImplementationClass="com.client.adf.cookieCartridge.claims.CookieClaimProcesor"
            Description="client Cookie claim processor.">
            <RequestStart>
                <InputClaims/>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim1" />
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim2" />
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim3" />
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:client:claim4" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </RequestStart>
        </ClaimProcessorDefinition>
    </ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
</CartridgeDefinition>
```

This is the skeleton of the implementation of the custom cartridge :

[image: CookieClaimProcesor Class]

Thank You!!!

Regards.
yeremy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Tridion version that you are using is prior 2013 SP1 you should execute your logic in onRequestStart. I noticed that you don't have code in your onRequestStart, please put the logic to create/populate your claims in that method.

In Tridion 2013 SP1 there is a new syntax that allow us to include the scope for a claim added/populated using the API.

```
claimStore.put(claimUri,value,ClaimValueScope.REQUEST)
claimStore.put(claimUri,value,ClaimValueScope.SESSION)
```

Comment: Could you guys clarify how this answer fits the question? It seems to me that the code should be in request start regardless of the Tridion version, and the logging should have worked regardless (but probably didn't due to incorrect /missing logback configuration). Was the code in onSessionStart and moving it to onRequestStart fixed it? Did you fix the logging too? Future visitors might want to know :)

Comment: Yes Peter, I moved the logic from onSessionStart to OnRequestStart and it started working. Now i can see in the logs that my claims are being put in the claimsStore, but actually, I cannot see the in the log some intries i wrote in the code.

Comment: @PeterKjaer I did not get it eiter but speaking to Yeremy explained it. The code listing in the question is not complete, the OnSessionStart() contains logging and some other code. None of the logging was triggered due to logging configuration. Moving the code from OnSessionStart() to OnSessionRequest() did not fix the logging, but at least got the business logic to work.

Comment: If you already had a ADF session before (from previous debugging) the OnSessionStart() will not be triggered and the code you had in there was not executed. To start a new session clear the ADF cookies in your browser and reload the page. That will force a new session (the ADF session id is kept in the cookie) and hence will trigger the OnSessionStart().

Comment: @EricHuiza Why do you say "prior 2013 SP1 you should execute your logic in onRequestStart"? ADF in Tridion 2011 also supports OnSessionStart(), OnRequestStart() and OnRequestEnd().

Comment: @JanH, in Tridion 2011 claims that were added/populated with the API are always Request, in Tridion 2013 SP1 there is a new syntax that allows to specify the Scope.

Comment: In general, don't use onSessionStart. If your application pool is recycled, your ADF claim store is cleared but your cartridge's onSessionStart will not be called again. It's best to use onRequestStart in all cases and just check the claim store to see if you need to do "start of session" stuff (i.e. your session-level claims are not there)